# AWS auto-scaling CPU utilization alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I have an auto scaling group with the following scaling policy:

```
Policy type: Target Tracking scaling
Execute policy when: As required to maintain Average CPU Utilization at 20
Take the action: Add or remove instances as required
Instances need: 30 seconds to warm up after scaling
Disable scale-in: No
```

So using this policy I'm trying to achieve the CPU load < 20% in the group.

Now if I look at Cloud Watch, I see the following alarm automatically created by the tracking policy:

[image]

and what I don't get is:

1. Why the threshold is 14? The value I set in the scaling policy is 20.
2. Why is it constantly in the alarm state? It's a few hours have passed now since that spike on the chart and the window is 15 minutes.
3. The `Threshold` line says "CPUUtilization < 14 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes"? Does it imply the normal operation mode or the circumstances when the alarm fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what the Target Tracking policy trying to do is to keep CPU load at 20%, not below 20%.

It is always on alarm state because the load is below thereshold and it can not remove anymore instance to keep CPU load close to target

The theresold described there imply condition that alarm fires

To achieve what you want, you can use the "simple scaling policies"
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I can simply ignore these alarms without making any changes to my policies.